# Rubygems Loading Wrong Version of Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, activemodel

I'm working on a Gem.

Despite specifying the version of activemodel, the gem is actually using activemodel 4.0.0.
As of 4.0.0 the constructor only takes a single argument. So when I try and pass in a second argument I get an Argument error:

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:180:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

**Why is Rubygems using the wrong version of ActiveModel?**

I have specified the following dependencies in the gemspec:

```
  gem.add_dependency "log4r"
  gem.add_dependency "deep_end"
  gem.add_dependency "google_drive"

  gem.add_development_dependency 'rake'
  gem.add_development_dependency 'rspec'
  gem.add_development_dependency "activemodel", "3.2.13"
  gem.add_development_dependency "activerecord", "3.2.13"
  gem.add_development_dependency "activesupport", "3.2.13"
```

My Gemfile.lock looks like this:

```
PATH
  remote: .
  specs:
    drive_time (0.0.1)
      deep_end
      google_drive
      log4r

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    activemodel (3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activesupport (3.2.13)
      i18n (= 0.6.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    deep_end (0.0.1)
      log4r
    diff-lcs (1.2.4)
    faraday (0.8.7)
      multipart-post (~> 1.1)
    google_drive (0.3.6)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4, != 1.5.2, != 1.5.1)
      oauth (>= 0.3.6)
      oauth2 (>= 0.5.0)
    httpauth (0.2.0)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    jwt (0.1.8)
      multi_json (>= 1.5)
    log4r (1.1.10)
    mini_portile (0.5.0)
    multi_json (1.7.7)
    multi_xml (0.5.4)
    multipart-post (1.2.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.0)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    oauth (0.4.7)
    oauth2 (0.9.2)
      faraday (~> 0.8)
      httpauth (~> 0.2)
      jwt (~> 0.1.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rake (10.1.0)
    rspec (2.13.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    rspec-core (2.13.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activerecord (= 3.2.13)
  activesupport (= 3.2.13)
  drive_time!
  rake
  rspec
```

I also get the following:

```
$ bundle show activemodel #/Users/pedr/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything I could think of, the following has done the trick (though whether it has permanently cured the issue, only time will tell).

1. `$ gem clean`
2. Uninstall rbenv
3. Install rbenv
4. Delete Gemfile.lock
5. `$ bundle`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running your code with `bundle exec`, otherwise ruby will default to using the most recent version of the gem you have installed.

Using `bundle exec` will disallow loading of any gems not in your bundle and should correct your problem. Check out the [manpage](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-exec.1.html) for more details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This wasn't the problem in this case, but it is excellent advice.